# Puedo hacer layouts con el mismo nombre y al mismo tiempo ponerles el mismo id para luego llamarlos?

Tags: java, android

Al intentar adaptar mi aplicación a otros dispositivos (tablets) me esta dando error, por lo siguiente, mi layout (que he llamado activity_wine_list) lo tengo adaptado para diferentes situaciones, lo he creado segun la situacion de una forma u otra, de esta forma:

Esto para el modo movil.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/list">

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Este es para tablet modo vertical:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>


    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/winery">

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Y este último tambien para tablets pero modo horizontal:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>


    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/winery"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Utilizan el id "list" y el id "winery", bien pues, el problema es que al hacer correr la aplicacion me da error indicandome que no encuentra el id "list" no me dice nada sobre "winery" entiendo porque mi primera condicion es verificar el list.

Aqui el codigo para la actividad:

```
public class WineListActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //This here, will choose one of the three options I have in R.layout.activity_wine_list.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wine_list);

        //Visible Toolbar.
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        //I ask if they have already the listFragment
        if (findViewById(R.id.list) != null) {
            Fragment listFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.list);
            //If no exist, I created it.
            if (listFragment == null) {
                listFragment = new WineListFragment();
                //Once is created, now add the fragmentManager to it
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.list, listFragment).commit();
            }
        }
        //Them, I goona do something like that but, with the winery.
        if (findViewById(R.id.winery) != null) {
            Fragment wineryFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.winery);
            if (wineryFragment == null){
                //Set newInstance because my WineryFragment have it has as an argument
                wineryFragment = WineryFragment.newInstance(0);
                //And them, just the same.
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.list, wineryFragment).commit();
            }
        }
    }
}


Aqui el codigo Fragment: 

public WineListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wine_list, container, false);

        //Reference to ListView
        ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        //Acceding Winery
        Winery winery = Winery.getInstance();

        //List adapter
        ArrayAdapter<Wine> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<Wine>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, winery.getWineList());

        //Saying the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //What to do when the user press one item on the list.
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent wineryIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), WineryActivity.class);
                wineryIntent.putExtra(WineryActivity.EXTRA_WINE_INDEX, i);
                startActivity(wineryIntent);
            }
        });

        return root;
 }

}
```

Y por último el codigo de donde saco las constantes:

```
public class WineryFragment extends Fragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    public static final String ARG_WINE_INDEX ="jhon.casique.baccus.controller.fragment.WineryFragment.ARG_WINE_INDEX";

    private ViewPager mPager = null;
    private ActionBar mActionBar = null;
    private Winery mWinery = null;

    //Creating new method to access him from WineryActivity. (newInstance)
    public static WineryFragment newInstance(int wineIndex){
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARG_WINE_INDEX, wineIndex);
        WineryFragment fragment = new WineryFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_winery, container, false);

        mPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new WineryPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));

        mWinery = Winery.getInstance();

        //Getting reference about the ActionBar
        mActionBar = (ActionBar) ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        //Listener.
        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

        //This value is for rotate the pageView and the ActionBar
        int initialWineIndex = getArguments().getInt(ARG_WINE_INDEX);
        //I ask to update my ActionBar and pageView to charge the wine it is pass as a argument.
        mPager.setCurrentItem(initialWineIndex);
        updateActionBar(initialWineIndex);

        return root;
    }

    //Creating method to update my data page wine (I gonna need a Winery)
    public void updateActionBar (int index) {
        mActionBar.setTitle(mWinery.getWine(index).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //Changing by position in the PageView name by name.
        updateActionBar(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_winery, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        boolean superValue = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_next && mPager.getCurrentItem() < mWinery.getWineCount() -1) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return true;
        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_prev && mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() -1);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return superValue;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItem menuNext = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_next);
        MenuItem menuPrev = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_prev);

        //Setting when they gonna be enabled.
        menuNext.setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() < mWinery.getWineCount() - 1);
        menuPrev.setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);
    }
}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradeceria mucho.

Gracias.

Actualizado 28/10

Agradezco por su ayuda pero, aun así esto me sigue dando error, en concreto este: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: jhon.casique.baccus, PID: 2238
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jhon.casique.baccus/jhon.casique.baccus.controller.activity.WineListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0057 (jhon.casique.baccus:id/list) for fragment WineryFragment{a50a4b98 #0 id=0x7f0b0057}

Por algun motivo el id "list" no lo reconoce y da igual si le hago refactor o haga lo que haga, no quiere funcionar. No entiendo que demonios pasa.

Answer (score 4):

> Puedo hacer layouts con el mismo nombre y al mismo tiempo ponerles el
> mismo id para luego llamarlos?

[Unicamente si se encuentran en diferente folder determinado por diferente tamaño.](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Por ejemplo un layout para modo vertical se agregaría en `/layout` para modo horizontal `/layout-land` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los calificadores para estos nombres de folders son,

para **Orientación**:

> **`land`**    Los recursos para las pantallas en la orientación horizontal (relación de aspecto).
>
> **`port`**    Los recursos para las pantallas en la orientación vertical (relación de aspecto de altura).

para **Tamaño**:

> **`small`**    Los recursos para las pantallas de pequeño tamaño.
>
> **`normal`**    Los recursos para pantallas de tamaño regular. (Esta es la línea de base de tamaño.)
>
> **`large`**    Los recursos para pantallas de gran tamaño.
>
> **`xlarge`**    Los recursos para pantallas de tamaño extra grande.

Por ejemplo:

Suponiendo deseas definir un layout para pantallas de tamaño extra grande y solo en orientación horizontal, lo agregarías dentro del folder:

**/layout-xlarge-land**

Solo para pantallas de tamaño grande y solo en orientación vertical, agregarías aquí tu layout:

**/layout-large-port**

---

De otra forma si lo que quieres es cargar varios layouts:

- modo móvil.
- Tablet modo vertical.
- Tablet modo horizontal.

Tendrías que especificarlos al llamar el método setContentView(), pero tendrían que llamarse diferente:

```
 if(!isTablet){ //móvil.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wine_list);
 }else{ //Tablet    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wine_list_tablet);
 }
```

Comment: Puedo añadir a tu respuesta agregando que en la documentación explican bien esto! https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters

Comment: Si claro, viene aún más especificada con los folder layout de tamaños

Comment: Muchas gracias has sido de muchisima ayuda. Lo he logrado hacer.

Comment: @Jhon si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 0):

El id como tal representa un identificador único, por ende cada layout debe tener un id único.
Ademas, si repites los id android no podra diferenciar entre los diferentes componentes, en el archivo R de los recursos.

Comment: Cierto pero existen momentos dónde tienes varios layouts para cada tipo de móvil entonces imáginate una aplicación en tablet y en un móvil pequeño el layout tendría que ser diferente para ambos sino la aplicación no tendría una buena interfaz ó, peor aun, mala experiencia de usuario

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por responder, he podido resolver el tema con vuestras respuestas.